# jQuery - How to call a callback with getjson

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following callback:

```
var getData = function (callback) {

    var id = $("#Id").val();

    if (id.length === 0)
       return; 

   $.getJSON('api/data' + '?id=' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        callback(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        return;
    });

}
```

I'm trying to call it as follows:

```
var id = 123;
getData(function () {
     //TO DO: check if id exist in data
     console.log(data);
});
```

But I get `reference error: data is not defined`. How do I get the data returned by the ajax request. I'm not too familiar with callbacks so bear with me as I'm still trying to get to grips with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `callback(data)`, you are simply calling the function you passed in to `getData`. You passed it one argument during the call, which means the function you passed in must have one argument present so that you can access it. Simply do:

```
getData(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

For a better understanding of what callbacks are and what's really going on, let's rewrite it to a simpler form.

```
function getData(callback) {

    var id = $("#Id").val();

    if (id.length === 0)
       return; 

   $.getJSON('api/data' + '?id=' + id)
    .done(function (data) {
        // 2. All that getData is doing is call that function using the
        //    reference you sent when it's done. Like any other function
        //    you can pass it arguments.
        getDataCallback(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        return;
    });

}

function getDataCallback(message){
  // 3. Like any other function, to access the arguments passed, you need
  //    to name your arguments.
  console.log(message);
}

var id = 123;

// 1. All you are doing really is pass a reference to a function to getData
getData(getDataCallback);
```

Where your code failed is at `console.log`. It tried to access `data` which is not defined anywhere, even on the outer scopes. That's equivalent to removing `message` from the arguments of `getDataCallback`.

Comment: so how would the callback work if it fails. would console.log show anything?